# How to export chart as image to excel in Chart.js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, chart.js, export-to-excel

I have created interactive charts using Chart.js in my MVC application. How to export this chart as a image in excel. I could not find any documentation for this in website.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['chart.js']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.labelspie = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales","Online Order"];
    $scope.datapie = [300, 500, 100, 400];
    $scope.optionspie = { legend: { display: true } };
```